# Pivot points add exit strategy

Tags: pivot, pine-script

I found this strategy on Tradingview based on pivot points. I tried to add an exit strategy on R3 / S3 but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(tradeDirection)
longCondition = crossover(Source, R1) and inDateRange
shortCondition = crossunder(Source, S1) and inDateRange

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=longCondition, oca_name="oca", 
oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
strategy.exit("Exit Long", stop=R3)
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=shortCondition, oca_name="oca", 
oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
strategy.exit("Exit Short", stop=S3)
```

Answer (score 0):

use limit for stop

```
if (buy)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="My Long Entry Id",limit=R1)
    
if (sell)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    
    strategy.exit("Exit short", from_entry="My Short Entry Id",limit=S1)
```